# How to let user dynamically specify database provider and connection details in C# EF4.1 Code First?

Tags: c#, database, ef-code-first, connection-string

I am in the process of creating a C# app to replace a VB6 app that uses a MySQL database where multiple copies of the app use the same database. The new app must be able to use the current MySQL database but I would also like it to be database agnostic so future instances of the app can use whatever server the user wants. In a perfect world, I would like the app on first run to present the user with a dialog that lets them choose the database type (MySQL, SQL Server, etc...) and specify the server ip, user, password, and database name. The app would then connect to that server and either use the database if it is already there or create a new database if it isn't.

Using Code First I have gotten to the point where I understand how to use the existing database or create a new one but only by hard coding the connection string in the App.config file.

```
    <add name="GumpIndexDatabase"
     connectionString="server=localhost;userid=123;password=123;port=3306;database=gump_new_data;pooling=false;"
     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
     />
```

I can change the connection string and provider before launching the app and everything works as expected. I can also change the connection string after launch, but not the provider, and I have to know whether the provider is MySQL or MSSQL in order to get the connection string details correct (ex: user or userid)

```
class GumpIndexDatabase: DbContext
{
    public GumpIndexDatabase(string connectionName)
        : base(MakeConnectionString(connectionName))
    {
    }
    private static string MakeConnectionString(string connectionName)
    {
         if (connectionName=MySQL) {
             //return MySQL string
         } else {
             //return SQL Server string
         }
    }
```

Hours of searching have not turned up an example of how to do such a thing, so I'm suspecting it isn't allowed or recommended, even though it seems like such a simple thing. I have seen some articles on connection string builder but did not understand how to get a database specific string from the generic objects.

So the simple question: how to specify the database connection details at run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend enforcing this feature, unless you 100% positive you cannot live without it. It adds a lot of maintenance tasks, that may not be obvious just now (such as updating to newer versions, bug fixes, spending lots of time to figure out common interfaces, maintaining those interfaces, hell lot of testing, etc). So unless it is a requested business feature - forget about it.

However, given you know what you are doing, this problem is generally solved via interfaces. There may be these common interfaces (it's a task by itslef to figure out them):

- `IConnection`
- `IDataProvider`
- `IRepository<T>`

At the moment you will implement interfaces using MySql database, such as `class MySqlConnection : IConnection`. If you need MS SQL, `class MsSqlConnection : IConnection`.

Effectively you must abstract all the functionality into common interfaces. You will have to provide implementations for each database/storage engine you want to support. At runtime, you will use IoC container and DI principle to set up the current implementation. All the child dependencies will use interfaces passed in as parameters to constructor (or properties or methods)

Comment: Wow, that sounds amazingly complex. Since the *only* place my app needs to know what server it is using is the App.config file it is hard to believe it is so hard to do this dynamically. All of my queries will be simple Linq so nothing would really change in the app if I used MySQL or MSSQL. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Matt I get your point and I have done this for couple of projects. The problem is with LINQ, at some point, just before it gets sent over to the server, it must be converted into SQL (MSSQL T-SQL or MySQL SQL whatever it is). So at some point of time LINQ must know to which database it is connected. They are all competing with each other, so there is no single universal SQL language that's supported by all the dbs. Therefore, a provider for each database must be different. You can probably search for: `generic repository c# sample`, and you should be able to find couple of good samples.

Comment: Maybe I need to rephrase - I know the provider must be different that is why I want to let the user choose it. Then that choice would determine what type of database object is created and that would take care of translating my Linq queries to Db specific queries. Possibly I'm just missing something but it seems simple enough.

Comment: Such translation of LINQ to SQL is a difficult task. It possibly took many man-years to develop and test a single provider. I'd be very interested to learn if there is a simpler way of doing things. But for you it doesn't matter, as you wold just use existing providers. What *you* need to implement in this case, is an abstraction in terms of interfaces, and implementation, that in tern call factual provider like (EF, NHibernate, ADO.NET, etc)

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer although it is more-or-less saying "you can't do that!"  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `Database` property?

```
GumpIndexDatabase.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "your conn string";
```

I just tested it **very short**, so no guarantee it works without problems. But I was successful using it in the contructor of one of my service layer classes:

```
public class MyService
{
    protected DataContext DataContext { get; set; }

    public MyService(DataContext dataContext)
    {
        DataContext = dataContext;
        DataContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "conn string";
    }
}
```

Just saw that `DbContext` has an overload `DbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)`. You should be able to use this too.

### Using an existing connection

Or you use an existing connection. Your `DbContext` should have something like this:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbConnection existingConnection)
        : base(existingConnection, true) { }
}
```

And then initialize it whereever you need to:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var connString = "whatever"; // could also be something like Textbox1.Text
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        var context = new DataContext(connection);
    }
}
```

Of course `SqlConnection` can be anything that inherits from `DbConnection`. See [DbConnection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-AT/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.aspx).

Comment: Yes, that is what I can do to set the string if I already have the string, but how to create one without hard coding different versions? Plus I still need to change the provider.